# Como alterar datas do formato americano y/m/d para d/m/y?

Tags: php

Comprei alguns sistemas porem todos vem com campos de datas em inglês, e também no padrão americano: ano/mês/dia.

Como faço para converter para o formato dia/mês/ano?

Comment: E esta data se encontra onde? No banco de dados? No arquivo PHP?

Comment: Anthony, bemvindo ao Stackoverflow. Pode explicar melhor a sua pergunta e ser mais claro no que procura. Eu percebo que quer converter o formato de datas mas não faço ideia de onde o quer fazer...

Comment: Se puder postar o código e o banco de dados ajuda bastante, lia o guia [ask] e depois [edit]e sua pergunta.

Comment: Ele quer converter o formato no PHP, a [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/25512/7210) é que o AP pretende.

Comment: Tome cuidado, se tiver alguma ligação com uma base de dados como o MySQL, você deve fazer todos os *inserts* no formato americano.

Answer (score 12):

```
<?php
echo date('Y/m/d'); // retorna a data nesse formato ano/mês/dia, essa data é a atual do servidor você pode alterar da forma que desejar exemplo date('d-m-Y')

echo date('d/m/Y',  strtotime($variavel)); // convert a data da $variavel para o formato dia/mês/ano
?>
```

Te aconselho usar notepadd++ ou dreamweaver o recurso de pesquisar nos arquivos, assim você pesquisa onde tem date, data, $date algo assim ate encontrar e usar a segunda opção que convert para nosso formato mais comum

Answer (score 3):

Talvez você possa utilizar o `locale`. 
Veja um exemplo:

```
<?php
/* Define o local para Holandês(usar pt_BR para o Português(Brasil) ) */
setlocale (LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');

/* Mostra: vrijdag 22 december 1978 */
echo strftime ("%A %e %B %Y", mktime (0, 0, 0, 12, 22, 1978));

/* Tenta diferentes nomes de local para o Alemão apartir do PHP 4.3.0 */
$loc_de = setlocale (LC_ALL, 'de_DE@euro', 'de_DE', 'de', 'ge');
echo "Preferred locale for german on this system is '$loc_de'";
?>
```

Referências:

- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setlocale.php
- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.locale.php

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar um conjunto de funcões da seguinte forma:

Passando do formato americano para formato brasileiro:

```
implode('/', array_reverse(explode('-', $data)));
```

E Passando do formato brasileiro para formato americano:

```
implode('-', array_reverse(explode('/', $data)));
```

**Links:**

**explode():** http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php

**implode():** http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php

**array_reverse():** http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-reverse.php

Answer (score 1):

Para converter as datas a partir de qualquer formato que essa data venha, você pode usar a classe nativa do PHP DateTime.

Veja um exemplo:

```
<?php
 $data = '2014/07/17';
 $data_brasil = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $data);

 print_r($data_brasil->format('d/m/Y')); //17/07/2014
```